# Protractor dynamically create Spec file

Tags: protractor

For data driven run I want to dynamically create required number of spec files in Conf file. For below code I get TS2304: Cannot find name 'buildspecs'

```
buildSpecs: function buildSpecs()
{

    let specsToBeRun;
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        specsToBeRun = 'MySpec' + i + '.js'
    }
    specsToBeRun = '[' + specsToBeRun + ']'
    return specsToBeRun
},

         exports.config = {
             specs: buildSpecs(),
         },
```

Comment: Where did you define the function `buildSepcs()`? in protractor conf.js or a separate file.  Please show your code to import the definition of  function `buildSepcs()`

Comment: @yong thanks. I have since updated conf.js code to be: let spec_files = "Tests/Spec0.js, Tests/Spec1.js,";     exports.config = {    specs: [spec_files], } The code runs but opens and closes the browser. If I update the code to let spec_files = "Tests/Spec0.js";     exports.config = {    specs: [spec_files], }  it opens browser and runs test. I want to eventually have 'let spec_files' be assigned a function return value which will be all the various spec files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your given code, I guess you define `buildSpecs()` is another js file, not in protracor conf.js.  I will give a example for such case.

```
// buildSpecs.js
module.exports = {
    buildSpecs: function()
    {

        let specsToBeRun;
        for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
            specsToBeRun = 'MySpec' + i + '.js'
        }
        specsToBeRun = '[' + specsToBeRun + ']'
        return specsToBeRun
    },
};


// protractor conf.js
var buildSpecs = require('buildSpecs.js').buildSpecs;

exports.config = {
    specs: buildSpecs(),
};
```

If you define `buildSpecs()` in protractor conf.js, please update your question to show the entire conf.js.